# where can I get resource such as Blockchain technology in C++

Tags: blockchain, c++, learning

I have found a lot of pdf files about Ethereum smart contract and JavaScript cryptocurrency. I still want to know about resources such as C++ cryptocurrency. Let me know about some good resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best pdf about bitcoins would be the original white paper by Satoshi Nakamoto https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf

For programming free ressources I invite you there: https://www.lopp.net/bitcoin-information/developer-tools.html

Then you have some great book like "mastering bitcoin" or "programming bitcoin"

Comment: I also searching some tutorials about C++ cryptocurrency (create block /POS or POW/wallet and block explore.)